# CSS: Margin problem with Safari

Tags: css, safari, margins

On the [**site I'm working on**](http://like-o-potomo.us), for some reason the margin is needing to be different for Safari than in FF, IE8, Chrome & Opera? I have a link that I want lined up next to a label. It's lining up fine in all but Safari which needs a 12 pixel difference. Here's a screenshot to better describe the issue: [**Click**](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/8665/323201185022pm.png)

The Safari screenshot shows the label down too low. This is the CSS I use for the working 4 browsers:

```
.submitter a {
    float: right;
    margin: -2px 0 0 2px;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

And here's the code that works for Safari, however, usig it throws the link UP 12 pixels.

```
.submitter a {
    float: right;
    margin: -14px 0 0 2px; Works in Safari & Chrome
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Anyone able to shed some light on this? TIA

Comment: Heads up, its happening on Chrome 10 under Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to sort it out:

```
.submitter a {
    float: none;
    display: inline !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}
```

It's really very convoluted in there due to nonsensical use of the cascade.

Some rules are being applied to elements where they really shouldn't be due to selectors like:

```
.box_777 ul li a
```

You'd be better replacing that selector with something like:

```
.individual-likes > a
```

But, it's difficult to predict how improving your selectors will change how your page displays.

Comment: That did the trick Thirtydot. Thanks. And I couldn't agree more about the convolution. Finally learning CSS in more depth than small tweaks, so this is my "learning site", lol.

Comment: No problem. Just to make sure, what browsers did you try? I only tested in Firefox and IE8.

Comment: So far I've tested the fix in FF3 (latest), IE8, Opera 11, and Safari 5, all on Win7 x64. I haven't checked under Chrome 10 in Ubuntu or IE7 yet as @bstruthers & @derek hunziker mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it goes up like that could be because of the - pixel value. Are they nested correctly in the div? And did you apply the same alignment (CSS, Html, etc.) for the Chrome buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the site, the anchor is being set to `block` by `.box_777 ul li a` and then floated right by `.submitter a`.

If I remove the `display: block;` and `float: right;` things align.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on, but you might try one of the following:

```
.submitter .smalltext { float: left; }
```

(or)

Move the "follow" anchor tag before the "smalltext" span