# Margin between h1 on macbook

Tags: html, css

I have the website and between `h1` tags I have `5px` margin. But on macbook this margin doesn't appear but I don't know why. What should I do?

My code is simple (is't just a part of my css file):

```
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try other browsers?

Comment: Yes, on Chrome on MacBook this margin does'nt appear as well.

Comment: On my IE also this doesn't appear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413954/css-margin-problem-with-safari

Comment: You should include all code to replicate this issue. That includes the HTML and specifically how you are referencing the CSS. Can you confirm that the CSS is in fact loaded correctly (not cached either)

Answer (score 0):

Add These line in Your Code

```
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1{
        width:100%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
</style>
<h1>this is test</h1>
```

Comment: will be better to add some explanation to your solution.